# ASP.NET DropDownList.SelectedValue has not value on PostBack with dynamic data-binding

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

**Setup**
Using: Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.
Language: C#.
Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.
ViewState: I have disabled ViewState in the Web.Config - i.e.   `<configuration><system.web><pages enableViewState="false" />`.

**Problem**
I have an ASP.NET page with a standard DropDownList control.
I have set EnableViewState="true" and ViewStateMode="Enabled" on the DropDownList.
I'm using data binding in the code-behind to populate the control (this works fine).
Data binding happens in a call from Page_PreRender, on both initial load and post-back.
In a call from a Button Click event handler (i.e. before the Page_PreRender) I am trying to read from the SelectedValue property of the DropDownList.
The problem is: all I ever receive is a zero-length-string ("") value and inspection of the object indicates the control contains to values.

**Solution**
Ensure EnableViewState="true" is set within the <%@ Page %> directive on the page containing the DropDownList.

Alternatively, you could create an extension method for the DropDownList that reads the value from the HttpRequest collection.
e.g.

```
public static string GetSelectedValue(this System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList listBox)
{
  return HttpContext.Current.Request[listBox.ClientID];
}
```

Comment: Regarding the extension method solution:
This will fail (.ClientID value is wrong) when the DropDownList is in a custom UserControl, regardless of if <configuration><system.web><page clientIDMode="Static"> in web.config is set or not.  
Reason: clientIDMode is one cause (it changes the value to no include the UserControl ID). However, when clientIDMode is not "Static", the control name/key for the DropDownList in the Request collection uses a "$" separator whereas .ClientID for the control returns with "_". The solution is to use the .UniqueID property of the DropDownList.

Comment: I also tested this under Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5. The same issue arose when not including EnableViewState in the @Page directive.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct (aside from UniqueID as Jason pointed out)

but why are you disabling viewstate globally? it is one of the great perks of asp.net and necessary for lots of functionality in your pages. It isn't that bad for most controls so no reason to fear it.

You want to keep an eye on controls that generate a lot of markup (such as grids) and definitely disable it on those.

Just turn on Trace in your Page directive, and you will see how much viewstate is being used by each node on your control tree.

Comment: RE disabling ViewState - it's a combination of factors but largely personal preference. I've been developing since before ViewState was around and still prefer to work close to the metal and without "magic". I also prefer an "additive" approach to development (add as required) rather than reductive (remove as required).